# onBackPressed() to Home Screen not to Login Page

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

I have this sign in/register page. When you log in, it will go to membership page(fragment) and now I want to go back to the home page of the phone without logging out  but whenever I click back built in button it goes to the past page activities.

I tried this `android:noHistory="true"` but when i click sign in but i didnt sign in, just backstack.  the sign in/register page not appearing anymore.

Comment: i don't see any code, but you can try to add some logic in your login page to check if user has been login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would never like to navigate back to the login activity simply use the line of code

```
finish();
```

after your call to startAcitivty(). This will close the activity and won't be available to navigate back to without restarting the app or specifically calling the activity later in your code.

Or just Override onBackPressed() to finish.